# Manual JSON array with Coldfusion - works until I replace with Dynamic Values

Tags: coldfusion

For reasons beyond my control, I need to manually create a JSON structure to post to an API.  I've done so as follows;

```
<cfsavecontent variable="JSONData">
{"data":[{"Last_Name":"#lastname#",
"First_Name":"#firstname#",
"$gclid":"#zc_gad#",
"Email":"#email#",
"Phone":"#phonenumber#",
"Lead_Source":"PPC",
"Build_Cost_text":"#buildcost#",
"Estimated_Sales_Value_text":"#estsalesvalue#",
"Stage_of_Build_Work":"#stageofbuildingwork#",
"Work_Starting_Date_text":"#workstartdate#",
"No_Of_Units_text":"#numofunits#",
"Address_of_Development":"#devaddress#",
"Do_you_require_a_quote_for_building_control1":"#bcquote#",
"Gross_Floor_Area_text":"#grossfloorarea#",
"Development_Use":"#devuse#",
"Please_share_any_additional_information":"#additionalinfo#",
"Product_Type":"Warranty","Company":"#company#"}]}
</cfsavecontent>
```

(The actual code doesn't have linebreaks - it's just a bit harder to read!)

I then use that to post to the API;

```
<cfhttp method="POST" url="APIurl" result="postresult">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="oauthtokenvalue">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-type" value="application/json" />
<cfhttpparam type="body" value="#JSONData#" />
</cfhttp>
```

If, instead of populating it with dynamic values, eg "#lastname#" is hardcoded as "Smith", it works just fine.

However, as soon as I add the dynamic tags, I get the following error;

```
Can't cast Complex Object Type Struct to String
```

Changing the cfhttpparam (for the sake of testing) to;

```
<cfhttpparam type="body" value="#SerializeJSON(JSONData)#" />
```

Makes no difference either.

If it matters, above this is the cfquery that retrieves the record(s), then this is wrapped in a cfoutput query - and aside from the dynamic references, that's the only difference between the 'working' code and non-working code.

Comment: What is lastname, if coldfusion says it's a struct and you're trying to use it as a string? Additionally, if the reason you're doing this manually is to ensure the case of the json keys are correct, there's a way around that without doing it manually

Comment: @Kevin B - they are just values from a MySQL database record, all just regular text (previously entered via a <form>)

Comment: Sounds very similar to your question, "Zoho CRM Insert Record using JSON / Coldfusion" from earlier this week.  I suggest rereading that answer.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk It's the same project, yes. I had indeed tried the other suggested approach, but I get the same error. Both methods (now) work fine with 'hardcoded' data, but not dynamic.

Comment: effectively... if coldfusion says it's a struct... it's probably a struct. the path forward at that point would seem... clear, you need to inspect it and figure out why it is a struct and alter your code to consume the data appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SaveContent saves whatever you are *outputting* to a string. The code you are showing may not be outputting anything. Instead, it's possible that you are creating a struct. To make sure you are outputting the JSON, add a  tag as follows:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="JSONData">
<cfoutput>
{"data":[{"Last_Name":"#lastname#",
"First_Name":"#firstname#",
...
}]
}
</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
```

But, a better way to do this would be to use SerializeJSON(). I can't think of a reason why you wouldn't be able use it. For example:

```
<cfscript>
myQuery = queryExecute(...);
myData = {
    "data": []
}
for (record in myQuery) {
    arrayAppend(myData.data, {
        "last_Name": record.lastName,
        "First_Name": record.firstName
        ...
    });
}
WriteOutput(SerializeJSON(myData));
</cfscript>
```

Either way, you need to view your string to debug, which should give you a better idea of what the problem is. I would add a `<cfdump var="#jsonData#">` after you've created your string to see what it looks like. You could also output `<pre>#EncodeForHTML(jsonData)#</pre>` or `<pre>#HTMLEditFormat(jsonData)#</pre>` to see it.

But the bigger question is why you need to build the json manually. I know you say it's for reasons beyond your control. Perhaps you're using an old version of ColdFusion?? It doesn't matter what version of CFML you're using, you should still be able to loop over a query and append a struct of the record's values to an array, and then output them using SerializeJSON(). If your issue is an old version of SerializeJSON() that is buggy, there are UDFs out there that work around some of the old problems with SerializeJSON(), or you could write your own that would be better than building a string.

Comment: That's the odd thing that I can't quite grasp with this - when I cfdump it, it shows fine - all strings, no structs and the data exactly as I'd expect - it's just when it reaches cfhttpparam that an error is being thrown back.

<cfscript> is something I've never used, though having recently returned to CF after a few years away, it does appear to be much more widely used, so clearly I need to start getting my head around that.

Comment: Adding to this, I've spent a few hours playing around with cfscript and that approach now works.  The reason I (incorrectly) thought I had to take the manual approach was because Zoho requires a certain structure to the data, and the previous examples I'd seen didn't allow me to to 'bake' that in. Your answer pointed me in the right direction to figure out how I could make it work.

Comment: @Lee glad you got it working. When you say cfdump shows fine - all strings no struct, you've implied that there are multiple strings, right? When you cfdump a string, it should show you a single string. Over the years I have found that CFML plays really nice with JSON. I don't think I've ever had any issues building native CFML data structures that another endpoint (or Javascript, etc) want, and then serializing to JSON them using SerializeJSON().